# How I can get ddl of all objects like table,triggers,procedures etc in SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: sql-server, ddl

I have create sample program in which i have get ddl of all objects like table, trigger etc using get_ddl methods which are:-

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE', TABLE_NAME) FROM USER_TABLES;
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TRIGGER', TRIGGER_NAME) FROM USER_TRIGGERS;
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('VIEW', VIEW_NAME) FROM USER_VIEWS;
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('FUNCTION', OBJECT_NAME) FROM USER_PROCEDURES WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'FUNCTION';
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('PROCEDURE', OBJECT_NAME) FROM USER_PROCEDURES WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE';
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('INDEX', INDEX_NAME) FROM USER_INDEXES ;
```

Now I m trying to create same sample for sql server to get ddl of all objects so I want to know that Is sql server 2008 supports get_ddl methods or there are any other tools for creating ddl of all objects. Please help how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

for source objects -

```
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]), OBJECT_NAME([object_id]), [definition]
FROM sys.sql_modules
```

for tables, indexes etc -

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/67b45a/how-to-generate-a-create-table-script-for-an-existing-table/